# What is the significance of a red exclamation mark?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

Keep it spoiler free please, just started the game and there's a red arrow on the map but I don't see anything quest related to interact with. It was in some alleyway in the starting town.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A red exclamation mark is a marker on the map which show you where is the next step of your quest. It sometimes just mean that you have to go there, while some other times you need to interact with an item around (those items often looks like red orbs) or to execute a special action like talking to someone.

By reading the Quest Log, you should find some additional information on the quest you are doing and the specific action you might have to do. If you have the name of the quest, you can also get some information about it on this [wiki page](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Colony_9_Quests) that can help you to go forward on your quest.